# How much is too much flattening with firebase data?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I'm looking to have posts that can can be replied to, which is a better structure?

1)

```
posts
  908239409234
      postText: "Whats up peeps?"
      replies:
            09283049830294: true
            a9s0dif09iasd9: true

replies
   09283049830294
      text: "Nm breh"
      imageURL: nil
    a9s0dif09iasd9
      text: "Nm breh"
      imageURL: nil
```

or 2)

```
posts
   908239409234
      postText: "Whats up peeps?"
      replies:
         09283049830294
            text: "Nm breh"
            imageURL: nil

        a9s0dif09iasd9
             text: "Nm breh"
              imageURL: nil
```

I see so many examples of databases that look like #1 where you store references to posts stored somewhere else to support flattening, but I don't see any advantages to not just going with option 2 if it can be done?

If the user is joining in on a post, they'll have the posts uid, and they can just add in under the "replies" with an autoID.

TL;DR, is it better to go with the flatter method or the method that is seemingly more efficient and requires searching through less information? Is there any reason to not go for option 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with no. 2. 
The reason is that with no. 1 you will have to do a query to get the reply data based on IDs. 
With firebase it is always better to write more and read less.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. I've just seen SO many examples of people encouraging #1 so I didn't know if I was way overestimating what it takes to query, but yeah #2 definitely makes more sense to me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you will reference replies at some points later. If your replies only relate to your post and no more, then option 2 is optimal because you will not need to fetch the replies. However, if you would like to have more complex feature that will query for replies that relate to some users for example, it will be better to store a reference to each reply as option 1. This is from experience with my app that kept growing and at some points, it is too slow to fetch a node because it has too many children, grandchildren, etc. and I had to flatten the database to make it fetch faster. I would suggest to think about the architecture of your app carefully.

Comment: I think my main worry about option 1 vs 2 is data usage. If I had 10,000  replies stored in the reply node, is it intense to go retrieve specific children from that list if you have the specific uids for them?

I've refactored to avoid having to search through potential thousands of posts/ replies, but if that's not a big issue then I'd definitely prefer to keep it as flat as possible.

Comment: My solution with my app was copy some data from the replies that I need to query along with its reference for a post to query more quickly but keep a majority of data in a separate node if I need to query for more details. I also defer fetching data or only fetch when user is in focus or scroll to the view. It's up to your app though. This is just from my own experience with my web app and it might not be applicable to your app.